# Detect when back button was used to navigate to page

Tags: javascript, html, back

I have a heavily interactive page that, while it does not use a form, does have objects that maintain state. This state is completely messed up when someone navigates away from the page and then comes back to it again with the back button. So, I'd like to be able to detect when someone uses the "back" button to navigate to my page, and have it reset the content at that point. How can I accomplish this?

I found [one other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332844/javascript-detect-when-page-has-been-navigated-back-to) that addressed this issue, but it is very out-of-date (from 2011), doesn't mention anything about support for Chrome, and I'd rather not use JQuery if I don't have to (I'm not using it anywhere else at the moment).

Comment: Are they going `forward` in your site, or onto other sites? If it is simply a case of them navigating to and fro in your site, you could use `localStorage` to maintain last page?

Comment: They could be going anywhere - I would assume they visit another website outside my domain and come back from there.

Comment: And the refer url is not enough?

Comment: Take a look here, this might have you covered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: @Bibberty I think this is what I was looking for, thanks.